# How to get all packages of the java application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way I can get all packages related to my application in runtime? *(e.g. list of strings)*

I am interested only in packages that are declared in my application and not interested in those that come from dependencies.

I tried to search them by the main class:

```
System.getProperty("sun.java.command")
```

But, in this case, I can only get a package of my main class.

I assume it may differ of application and how it's packed. But, now I am mostly working with Spring Boot apps that are packed as *jar*.

Comment: Is this possibly an XY problem?

Comment: @NathanHughes, that might work. But, I hope that there might be a more elegant solution than traversing zip.

Comment: @jaco0646, the question is on the first line. I just made a note on what I managed to do so far.

Comment: What I was [getting at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is that without knowing why you want a list of package names, it smells like a design flaw. Ideally there is a better design wherein you don't need this.

Comment: Yes, the reason why I need it is that I want to instrument in java agent all the classes of only my packages. This is the reason I need these packages list.

Comment: check my answer @dvelopp

Answer (score 2):

You should try in this way, specify the main class package and do filter

**spring boot main class package** `com.main`

```
Package[] p = Package.getPackages();

    for(Package p1 : p) {
        if(p1.getName().startsWith("com.main"))
            System.out.println(p1.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Some applications have two and more totally different packages at the same time. 
e.g.
com.dvelopp.app (there is the main class) 
and 
com.company.utils (there are some utils that I have in my project)
In this case the only com.dvelopp.app branch is traversed, right?

Comment: then check on `startsWith("com.dvelopp")` or `startsWith("com.company")`, but basically in spring boot all the packages should fall under main class package right? i'm mean which seems clear @dvelopp

Comment: That's applicable to Spring components. Non-spring managed classes can be in different packages(that's might be not very cool, but still). But, in this case, we still don't know about the existence of "com.company". Anyway, the answer is very good, but still, we have some cases this approach doesn't cover.

Comment: i'm interested to know if you don't mine @dvelopp

Comment: I basically mean it doesn't find packages outside the one with main class.

Comment: have you tried? it worked for me, it found all the packages in my spring boot application @dvelopp

Comment: Yes, It does find all the packages of spring boot app. But, here we are checking if they have same root path as package with main class (p1.getName().startsWith("com.main")), but what if some of my classes are not in com.main? we don't handle it.

Comment: If there are different structures, why don't you add couple of filter conditions? can you add your package structure, i just want to see @dvelopp

Comment: This code is in java agent, as I mentioned. It should be generic and know nothing about my packages structure. It should be able to read it. With the help of your code and System.getProperty("sun.java.command") I can find packages that have same root as main class for all the applications. It's generic. But, only because it's generic I can't really add startsWith("com.company") because then It will not be generic